# Passing jquery ajax array to php not working

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I know this HAS to be a duplicate. But I can't for the life of me figure out where it's going wrong.  I've tried passsing the array directly, using json encode/decode, joining the array in jquery and passing it as a string and exploding it....but I just can't get my php to run with the pass through data.  Help?!

There is something going on with quotes if I had to guess, but I'm striking out.  If I comment out the line that retrieves the array, and uncomment the two lines where i set the list and explode it, the script can be called by itself and works as expected. But in it's current form, it does nothing. I'm sure I'm missing something simple because I don't know enough about either language.

**EDIT: UPDATE:**
I was able to use:

```
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

to get the following response in the network console. Does this shed light as to why the script is failing to run when passed the array?

```
array(1) {
  ["download_listArray"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "7391-1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "7392-2"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "7393-3"
  }
}
```

**For completeness sake, here is the same response when using the JSON.stringify method:**

```
array(1) {
  ["download_listArray"]=>
  string(26) "["7391-1","7392-2","7393-3"]"
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
console.log(download_list);   \\ gives: ["7391-1", "7392-2", "7393-3"]

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "zip_download.php",
            data: {download_listArray:download_list},

            success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
        });
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$sample_name_list = $_POST['download_listArray'];

//$sample_name_list = "7391-1,7392-2,7393-3";    #If I use these two lines, the script runs as expected
//$sample_name_list = explode(",", $sample_name_list);

foreach ($sample_name_list as $i => $sample_name){

   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: It should work. What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Comment: I think your ` url: "zip_download.php",` is not correct, verify file path

Comment: @Barmar I am triggering this with a multiselect in a leaflet map. So any sort of dump, print, or echo doesn't show up. And I don't have the knowledge on how to get them to show up otherwise.  (If I navigate to the php directly, i can see the messages pop up in my window, but that doesn't do any good for the troubleshooting of the handoff.)

Comment: @AkhilAravind It's a generic sanitized link for the purpose of sharing. The actual link is correct, and I can navigate to it through my editor when i have the jquery file open.

Comment: @Barmar - I've updated the question with some debugging.  I did var_dump followed by die in order to see what came back in the network console.

Comment: `var_dump` shows the expected result. I can't see any reason why the `foreach` loop doesn't work.

Comment: Put `var_dump($sample_name_list)` before the `foreach`, what does it show?

Comment: @Barmar I think I have this narrowed down to being a problem with trying to download a file through the AJAX request.  I need to push the array to the php script, but the zip download that the script pushes back has to be redirected to a new window.  Not sure how to fit that into my jquery.

Comment: You can't do a download through AJAX. To do the download, open a window to a separate download script, and put the filename in the URL parameters.

Comment: @Barmar - but then how do you pass the array if you are opening the url a second time?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with AJAX. If you want to do a download, just open the download URL.

Comment: @Barmar I have to pass the php a list of filenames so that it knows what to download from a database.

Comment: Pass each filename to the script that actually performs the download, I don't see the need for a separate AJAX step.

Comment: The download script looks the name up in the DB, and sends the file.

Comment: If there's something I'm not understanding, edit the question and explain the whole process you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your update:

"*For completeness sake, here is the same response when using the JSON.stringify method*:

```
array(1) {
  ["download_listArray"]=>
  string(26) "["7391-1","7392-2","7393-3"]"
}
```

**Please find my updated code to solve your issue according to your given data**:

**PHP**:

```
<?php

$_POST['download_listArray'] = '["7391-1","7392-2","7393-3"]';

//var_dump($_POST['download_listArray']); die();

$sample_name_list = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['download_listArray']));

foreach ($sample_name_list as $i => $sample_name){

   echo $sample_name.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array into Json and try same as the following codeblocks. Hope that works for you.

Jquery:

```
var download_list= JSON.stringify(download_list);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "zip_download.php",
    data: {download_listArray:download_list},
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

---

PHP:

```
<?php
$sample_name_list = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['download_listArray']));

foreach ($sample_name_list as $i => $sample_name){
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I've tried several variations of that as well with no luck. I've tried using Json.strigify on  the array as well as a joined string. I've tried to read the JSON in PHP as you have above both with and without stripslashes, as well as with and without the key in the foreach loop.

Comment: I updated the question with the debugged output of your suggestion as well.